# Adding of third party library to angular2 via CLI doesn't work as I would expect

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add to my Angular2 project third party JS library **sockJS**...

**system.config.ts**:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
'sockjs-client': 'vendor/sockjs-client/'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'sockjs-client': { 
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'sockjs.min.js'
  }
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestProj</title>
  <base href="/">

  <script src="/vendor/sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js"></script>
  {{#unless environment.production}}
  <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  {{/unless}}
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

    {{#each scripts.polyfills}}
    <script src="{{.}}"></script>
    {{/each}}
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'sockjs-client';

declare var SockJS:any;
```

**Problem:**

if I run

```
ng build
ng serve
```

it works fine.

But if I remove from index.html

```
<script src="/vendor/sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js"></script>
```

and run:

```
ng build --prod
ng serve
```

I receive crash when using SockJS:

```
EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: SockJS is not defined
```

But I see clearly that sockjs.min.js is minifyed inside of main.js bundle....Please what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is requested angular-cli-build.js:

```
// Angular-CLI build configuration
// This file lists all the node_modules files that will be used in a build
// Also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'sockjs-client/sockjs.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: How does your `angular-cli-build.js` file looks like, can you add the same in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to make this to work is according the following link:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/949

so my angular-cli-build.js look like now:

```
// Angular-CLI build configuration
// This file lists all the node_modules files that will be used in a build
// Also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js'
    ],
    polyfills: [
          'vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
          'vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
          'vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
          'vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
          'vendor/sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js'
      ]
  });
};
```

After this, bundling in production mode:

```
ng build --prod
ng serve
```

works correctly and I can work with third party library in Angular 2.